# Eclipse Shortcut for Android Lifecycle methods

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Does the ADT introduces any shortcuts to create the life cycle methods using a keyboard shortcut, or is it necessary to create a code template to handle that job?

I know that it's possible to use Alt + Shift + S V but that is a huge list to pick from. I would just like to have all that are related to lifecycle

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: If you want particularly these you can have it at a notepad asset txt and just copy paste them. Too much fuzz for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Added a Macro instead of searching for more stuff... there doesn't appear to be a direct way of doing this, so this way works.

Answer (score 1):

Upon extending the `Activity` class, you can simply jump to a new line, type `"oncr"` and press CTRL+space and the `onCreate` method will pop up.

Similarly, simply typing `"onpa"` on a new line and then pressing CTRL+space will provide you with the respective method (onPause) right at the top of the list.